# Multi-line bash prompt if path is longer than x characters?

Tags: bash

I'd like to split my bash prompt into two lines if the path is "too long", so that the entered command always fits.

My current prompt looks like: `~/go/src/asd$ ls -lah`, so if the path is too long, the commands have to line wrap all the time. Thus, i'd like to conditionally make it a two-line prompt, if the path is too long. How can I do this?

Comment: Assume you are in `/data` and need to type `ln -s /zzzzzz/ccccc/vvvvvv/bbbbbb/nnnn /ssss/ddddd/fffff/ggggg/jkjkjkjkjkjkj` Parameter "too long" cant be counted in math. Such "precise" parameters works only for politics in their statements :)

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You can make it always 2 lines though

Comment: No, if the command is too long, that's fine. I just don't want the path in the prompt to be too long. By too long, I mean some constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
path_len() {
  max_path=20
  currentPath=$(pwd)
  pathLen=${#currentPath}
  [ ${pathLen} -gt ${max_path} ] && printf "\n:"
}

PS1="\n\[\033[1;31m\]\u@\h: \[\033[32m\]\w\$(path_len)\[\033[0m\] -> "
```

and adjust variable `max_path` in function `path_len` to that magic value that you called "too long" ;)